# Two integers $a$ and $b$ are coprime, is it possible that $a \mid b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility, coprime

Let $a$ and $b$ be coprime integers. Is it possible that $a \mid b$?

My thinking is that if $a \mid b$ then $a$ and $b$ share a factor besides $\pm 1$ ($a$ itself) and so are not coprime. Thus, $a \nmid b$.

This is probably very simple, but I'm still unsure.

Comment: You are right, $a$ can't divide $b$.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Yes you are right, since a will be a common factor of a,b if a|b they wont be coprime.

Comment: Absolutely, it suffices that $a=1$.

Comment: Why are you unsure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $a$ and $b$ are positive:

If $a\mid b$, then, since $a\mid a$, $\gcd(a,b)\geqslant a$. So, unless $a=1$, no, you cannot have both $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $a\mid b$.